# ¿Como crear archivo: php.ini correctamente para modificar el tamaño permitido de subida en archivos?

Tags: wordpress

En el hosting no viene creado el archivo de configuración: php.ini. ¿Cuál es el contenido que debe llevar si solo necesito ampliar el tamaño permitido en subida de archivos a la galería, y en que parte del directorio se debe guardar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un ejemplo para 50 mb podria ser así:

```
[PHP]
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
```

Comment: de acuerdo, ¿es todo lo que lleva el archivo cuando se crea?

Comment: gracias, saludos